# Guided bilinear interpolation: is it a known algorithm?

Tags: image-processing, interpolation

I have a function that's sampled relatively coarsely along one direction, $x$, and much more finely along another, $y$. Sampling grid is regular. I need to interpolate between all these samples, with the following requirements:

1. Computation of the interpolated function must be $O(1)$ with respect to data resolution (it'll be done in a GLSL shader, with data being in a texture);
2. Overshoots and ringing, like Runge or Gibbs phenomena, are undesirable;
3. The interpolation shouldn't look aligned to the sampling grid, it should look more "natural" (see below for details).

The first two points are satisfied by the usual bilinear interpolation. But the third one isn't.

Let's consider the following example function:

$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}2}\exp\left(-\frac{\left(y-18-6\sin\left(\frac{x-1}2\right)\right)^2}{x^2-2x+5}\right).$$

Its domain is taken to be $x\in[1,10],$ $y\in[1,30],$ and sampling will be done over integral points: $x=\{1,2,...,10\},$ $y=\{1,2,...,30\}.$

Plotting the function as a density plot, we'll get the following smooth blob:

[image: original function plot]

After sampling at integral points and doing bilinear upsampling, we'll get this "fluffy" blob, with noticeable rectangular cells:

[image: bilinearly upsampled function plot]

This fluff is due to interpolation being done along horizontal directions between finely-sampled rows, thus missing the actual direction of isolines of the original function, leading to this steppy effect.

I've made a customization where an additional step is performed before actually computing the interpolation: matching the points of the neighboring well-sampled 1D functions to find direction along which to interpolate. The results are saved into an additional table to enable $O(1)$ computation. The result looks as follows:

[image: customized bilinear filtering]

This interpolating function still crosses all the sampling points, but does it in a more intelligent way, trying to follow the isolines of the original function.

---

My **question** is: have I reinvented a wheel? Is there a well-known algorithm that does something similar to improve the result of interpolation and satisfy all three requirements listed above?

Comment: I bet this only works properly for your particular case and your particular data. A more general approach that would solve your problem is using a higher-order interpolation scheme, for example cubic spline interpolation works really well.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I was thinking "I'm gonna suggest spline interpolation, but I'm not sure how that looks in an image!"  Now I know...

Comment: @CrisLuengo cubic spline interpolation can lead to overshoot, see a simple example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMYkr.png . Thus, it explicitly doesn't satisfy requirement #2.

Comment: It won't lead to overshoot if your data is sampled correctly.

Comment: And if your data is not sampled correctly, well then you've lost information that you cannot recover.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sometimes it's infeasible to sample "correctly". E.g. a function may have a jump (or rapid increase) while the sampling is restricted to a regular grid (which is not that uncommon). Such function may be satisfactorily approximated by a linear interpolant, but Fourier or spline interpolants will necessarily have ringing. While the ringing may be satisfactory in some applications, it's often no good when processing images that are to be viewed by humans.

Comment: Typically interpolation means that the output is equal to the input at the sampling instants -- is this the case here?  _Edit your question_ to include that in your list of requirements.  And note -- I'm pretty sure that "no ringing", "exact on the sampling points", and "works with any data set" will end up being mutually exclusive, but I'd have to sit down and do some math to be sure.

Comment: @TimWescott I didn't change the definitions. Interpolation is interpolation, as you say. Quoting my own post: _"This interpolating function still crosses all the sampling points"_.

Comment: Superficially, it sounds a bit like Edge Detect upsampling. This has been around for quite some time, with detail upgrades over the years, most recently as FSR **1** (which was obviously bad for its intended purpose with much better temporal upsamplers available)

Comment: I am not sure I got what you actually did. What do you mean by the direction? What I can share is my knowledge about interpolation of Bayer Pattern. Their, advanced methods (Prior to Deep Learning) tried to infer something about the local direction of the data and interpolate along. It might be similar to what you do.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, There are splines which doesn't overshoot. Like MATLAB's `pchip()` and to some degree `makima()`.